# SOAP webservices : Axis2 1.6.2

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I have created SOAP web service with Axis2 engine ( server and client ) both using this [link](http://wso2.com/library/1719/)
It is working fine. Eclipse plugin for client ( code gen using WSDL) created stub, callback handler, exposed method classes etc. All fine till now.

One of my friend given some project which also contains client with using axis2. This that project I can see some files like below :

```
`
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="count" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "count"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "deleteMultipleResponse")
public class DeleteMultipleResponse {

    protected String count;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the count property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the count property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCount(String value) {
        this.count = value;
    }

}
`
```

There are multiple files in which I can see below and use of annotations.

```
` /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element name="count" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
`
```

The project which I have created using this [link](http://wso2.com/library/1719/) does not generated any such file and any file which uses annotations.

Can you please explain the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend seems to use JAXB data binding, while you are obviously not.

There are several different options available for AXIS2 data bindings (ADB,Axiom, Jaxb, etc.)

You might want to check out the  official Apache Axis2 tutorials to get a deeper understanding
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html#adb

Comment: is it JAXB or jibx. When I am trying to create client code from WSDL using Axis2 code gen plugin in eclipse, I am getting g 4 options in databinding name ie adb, xmlbeans, jibx, none. Are you talking about this `jibx` ??